# Determine which control has focus

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4

I am developing an app for iPod/iPhone and I am trying to determine which control has focus. I am new to XCode so my terminology may be incorrect, but I am looking for the object (control) where the user is currently typing.

Hope someone can help!!

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 2):

you need to call

```
[myTextField isFirstReponder]
```

This will tell you if myTextField has focus

There is also

```
[myTextField isEditing]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for just doing something on change of text in a control, you just need to wire up an IBAction to the control's change event and then everytime the text changes, your IBAction method will be called.

Comment: Yes, I get that, what I am really looking for is a way to find out which control has focus. I have a method that accepts a TextField and I want to pass the current text field to the function for processing.  So I need to get a handle to the currently active object (TextField).  Does that make sense?